# Make a bar chart in Chart.js with a legend that reflects the labels in the X-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In Charts.js, i am trying to create a bar chart with a single data set and each column being differently coloured.
The desired result would look like this:
[image]

However, when i try to create something like this, at best, i get the following
[image]

The following code is the chart config object used to initialise the chart:

```
var config_canvas_alerts = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    value0,value1,value2,value3,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#F7464A","#46BFBD","#FDB45C","#949FB1",
                ],
            }],
            labels: [
                "Move - Match " + value0,
                "Move - Unmatch " + value1,
                "Permit - Match " + value2,
                "Permit - UnMatch" + value3,
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                onClick: function (e, p) {
                    alert(p.text);
                },
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: '@Model.mgt_dash_alert.graph_title',
                position: 'top',
                fontStyle: 'normal',
                fontSize: 14,
                padding: 10
            }
        }
    };
```

I have tried to restructure the data so that each `data` value becomes its own dataset object with accompanying value, background colour and label but that didnt work out well either.

The only way i was able to achieve this (and hence how i generated the first screenshot) was by dynamically changing the graph from a pie chart to a bar chart after initialisation. The legend seemed to work well.

Changing dynamically from pie to bar chart is not ideal. Any suggestions here?

Comment: value0 comes from array or value0 itself  a variable?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It just repeats information that is already in the chart (as the x-axis labels). All this does is add noise and make the chart harder to understand. I'd recommend simply not showing the legend.

Comment: @timclutton the columns are clickable but for some users, trying to click on tiny columns may be a little difficult. A legend would solve this problem as the labels would be a clickable as well